# Git and branches

Tags: git, branch

ok so apparently to create a new git branch on the remote repository we need:

```
git push origin origin:refs/heads/sandbox
git fetch origin
git checkout --track -b sandbox origin/sandbox
git pull
```

Now if I want to switch back to the master branch I can just do

> git checkout master

If I want to switch back to sandbox after going back to master, do I need

> git checkout --track -b sandbox
>   origin/sandbox

or just

> git checkout sandbox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git checkout sandbox` will work.  When you did the `checkout -b sandbox origin/sandbox`, you set up a local branch named `sandbox` which will track the remote `origin/sandbox`.  To get the latest changes from upstream into your local copy, do `git pull` when on the `sandbox` branch.